# Need help creating a method that returns an array whose elements are squares of another array

Tags: java, methods, double

I have an assignment that requires me to create a method that takes an array of double named dArray as parameter and returns another array whose elements are squares of the elements of dArray.

For example,

if dArray is `{1, 4, 6, 7}`, the the returned array will be `{1, 16, 36, 49}`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is what I have written so far, but it doesn't work right.

```
public static double[] squareArray(double[] dArray) {
    double[] squareArray = new double[10];

    for(int i = 0; i < dArray.length ; i++) {
        dArray[] = dArray * dArray;
    }

    return squareArray;
}
```

Comment: java or javascript?  Why include both tags on your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String [ ] args) {
            double[] scores = {3, 9, 3, 3};
            double[] scoresSquared = squareArray(scores);
            for (int i =0; i <scoresSquared.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(scoresSquared[i] + " ");
            }
    }

    public static double[] squareArray(double[] dArray){
            double[] squareArray = new double[dArray.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < dArray.length ; i++){
                    squareArray[i]= dArray[i] * dArray[i];
            }
            return squareArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: `squareArray(double[] dArray[])` would receive only 2D array :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works great. Turns out I still need a lot more practice with arrays. I appreciate your help greatly!

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you are squaring the array more than you need to. If every element in the array needs to be squared, you should only have to loop over that array once, but in your code you have two loops.

That's part of the issue.

Another is that you're trying to multiply arrays, which isn't allowed. Inside that method, you need to loop over the array and square each element in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. In your squareArray(), create a List< Double> or something like that.
2. Iterate through each double in the double[] and add that double squared to the List.
3. Return (listname).toArray();

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.

- [Copy the contents of the array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) you're receiving and place them into your internal `squareArray`.
- Iterate over `squareArray` and apply your algorithm (to access specific indexes while in the loop, use `squareArray[i]`)
- Return `squareArray`.